# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority keycloak on cluster

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, x509certificate

I have keycloak deployed on the Azure app service, While using it locally through gocloak, it works fine, and when using it for service is deployed on the cluster it throws an error of x509: certificate signed by unknown authority keycloak on the cluster.

to reproduce this:
use keycloak API to request a token from the Golang service in VM and it will get an X509 error.

What I tried is disabling the tls request on the Keycloak client and realm.

do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?